# Class SoapClient Not Found through Task Scheduler

Tags: php, soap

I have a script that works perfectly if I run the page through the browser, but if I try to set the script to run with Windows Task Scheduler I get the

```
"Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found" error.
```

I have Soap extension enabled in the php.ini.  This is what I have set in the action for the scheduled task:

```
Program = D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.exe
Arguments  = -f D:\wamp\www\Web\ScheduledTasks\Import.php
Start In = D:\wamp\www\Web\ScheduledTasks
```

Here is the code that I am using for the SoapClient:

```
$Client = new SoapClient("https://www.domain.com/services/secureWebService.svc?wsdl",
        array('location' => 'https://www.domain.com/services/secureWebService.svc/soap',
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));

AddWCFUsernameToken($Client, 'Username', 'Password');

function AddWCFUsernameToken($Client, $username, $password) {
            $wssNamespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
            $username = new SoapVar($username, XSD_STRING, null, null, 'Username', $wssNamespace);
            $password = new SoapVar($password, XSD_STRING, null, null, 'Password', $wssNamespace);
            $usernameToken = new SoapVar(array($username, $password), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null,'UsernameToken', $wssNamespace);
            $usernameToken = new SoapVar(array($usernameToken), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, null, $wssNamespace);
            $wssUsernameTokenHeader = new SoapHeader($wssNamespace, 'Security', $usernameToken);
            $Client->__setSoapHeaders($wssUsernameTokenHeader);
        }
```

Like I said before if I run this page directly from the browser it works perfectly fine, but it only gives me this error when I try to have Windows Task Scheduler run the page.

Comment: You should enable soap module for cli scripts.

Comment: Well your answer made me rethink about the php.ini file and how there is two of them, one in the apache folder and one in the php folder.  The one in the php folder did not have the soap module turned on.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Andrej, need to make sure that both php.ini files have the soap module turned on, if you have two php.ini files.  I have two, one in the Apache folder and one in the PHP folder.